# What is a motivation for this theorem and what is an example this theorem is applied?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, motivation

If one doesn't know a motivation, it's hard to memorize such a theorem. So do I.

> Rudin RCA p.30
>
> Let $(X,\Sigma,\mu)$ be a measure space such that $\mu(X)<\infty$ and $f\in L^1(\mu)$.
>
> Let $S$ be a closed subset of $\mathbb{C}$
>
> If [$\forall E\in\Sigma, \mu(E)>0 \Rightarrow \frac{1}{\mu(E)}\int_E f d\mu \in S$], then $f(x)\in S$ almost everywhere.

Maybe since it's deserves to be marked as a theorem in the text, Rudin provided it.

A problem is, he never gives a motivation.

I don't know any motivation for this theorem (which looks similar to the mean value theorem to me). And in the hypothesis, why $S$ has to be closed? The theorem still holds even when $S$ is a $F_\sigma$ set. And what is an example this theorem is applied?

Comment: This follows from the Lebesgue differentiation theorem, which is one of the corner stones of integration theory, so you should really read and understand it.

Comment: Even so, this doesn't answer the OP's question (a possible response is "this is why this is a comment"). The point is not the proof, but rather why this might be important. Why would someone think this is relevant? I don't mean to be rude.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rudin later uses it to prove the [Radon-Nikodym theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon%E2%80%93Nikodym_theorem) (theorem 6.10 on pp. 121-123) as well as a couple of further results following Radon-Nikodym (theorems 6.12 and 6.16).